# How can I integrate Monero in a website using PHP?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

Can anyone please tell me how I can integrate Monero using PHP?
Do I need to install monero wallet first?
I am using [this](https://github.com/MalMen/PHP-Monero/blob/master/includes/Monero.php) Monero library, but don't know how to login to Monero by using it.
If I need to install a Monero wallet first, then how I can install it on my host?
I have searched a lot about this on the internet but failed to find anything

Answer (score 2):

The file you linked is not a Monero library. At most, all it shows is a couple of examples of calling the [RPC methods](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html), for which is an easy task in any coding language. Just run the `monero-wallet-rpc` application and call its [HTTP methods](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html).

If you want/need to use a library that wraps that up further, for example because you don't know how to call a HTTP based API or don't want to work with parsing JSON, there are a few Monero PHP wrapper libraries, such as [monero-integrations/monerophp](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp).

Regardless what library you use (if any), you will first need to create a wallet file (either with `monero-wallet-cli` or the Monero GUI wallet), then on your server, run `monerod` (the daemon) and `monero-wallet-rpc` (the thing that exposes RPC methods to work with your wallet).

Another approach is to use a payment processor, such as [GloBee](https://globee.com/). These have their own API but allow you to accept payments without needing to run a daemon or wallet RPC, useful if you don't have a hosting environment that you can install/run your own applications on.